# A finite element method example / problem area that is atypical

Tags: math

I am looking for an example that I can solve using Finite Element Method that is not mechanics / physics related. All examples in textbooks revolve around truss, beams, loads, etc. Does anyone know other areas preferably with known differential equation, and enough data to work with? From sociology perhaps, or climate prediction?

Comment: Climate prediction would still be physics, would it not?  It's a combination of fluid mechanics, heat and mass transfer on a global scale.

Comment: Actually climate prediction would be fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's commonly done, but the [Black-Scholes PDE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black%E2%80%93Scholes) for evaluating options might lend itself to a transient FEA solution.

Finite element methods apply to any ordinary or partial differential equation that lends itself to the method of weighted residuals.  You can apply it to far more than civil engineering beams: general non-linear solid mechanics, heat transfer, fluid mechanics, acoustics, etc.  Those are all still physics, of course.

Comment: Do you think it would be possible to utilize FEA for stock price prediction? I guess this would be different than evaluating options.

Comment: I don't know what the differential or integral equation would be.  I'm not sure that it would be very useful.  Usually these things are done with Monte Carlo simulations, because they're statistical in nature.  There are too many Black Swans for the problem to be deterministic.

Comment: Black scholes equation is heat equation, and people use finite difference here. FEM are used in finance, but for more complex things.

Answer (score 2):

I read people using FEA methods for examining the spread of infections by viruses. A quick search on epidemiology simulation might shed some more light into the matter.